# set value to new column according to specific index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I want to create new column name `pred_date` in `df` and set value according to specific indexes.

For example for indexes `[1, 2, 3]` I want to set value as the value in the `date` column.

`df`:

```
    date   label    
1   1.1     1  
2   2.1     0
3   3.1     1 
4   4.1     1
```

Expected output `df`:

```
    date   label    pred_date    
1   1.1     1       1.1 
2   2.1     0       2.1
3   3.1     1       3.1
4   4.1     1       Nan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `index.isin` + `where`:

```
df['pred_date'] = df['date'].where(df.index.isin([1,2,3]))
```

Output:

```
   date  label  pred_date
1   1.1      1        1.1
2   2.1      0        2.1
3   3.1      1        3.1
4   4.1      1        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.Series.where`:

```
df['pred'] = df['date'].where(df.index != 4)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   date  label  pred
1   1.1      1   1.1
2   2.1      0   2.1
3   3.1      1   3.1
4   4.1      1   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[[1, 2, 3], 'pred'] = df['date']
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   date  label  pred
1   1.1      1   1.1
2   2.1      0   2.1
3   3.1      1   3.1
4   4.1      1   NaN
```

Or:

```
df['pred'] = df.loc[[1, 2, 3], 'date']
```